# Flutter TabBarView is not working in release mode

Tags: android, flutter

Flutter TabBarView is not working in release mode when widget first initilized but after recall the widget it works. For better understanding check demo gif.

```
static const List<Tab> tabs = <Tab>[
Tab(child: Text("Latest")),
Tab(child: Text("Business")),
Tab(child: Text("Entertainment")),
];

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final isDarkTheme = Provider.of<ThemeNotifier>(context).darkTheme;
return DefaultTabController(
  length: tabs.length,
  child: Scaffold(
    appBar: PreferredSize(
      preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight),
      child: Container(
        color: isDarkTheme ? kSecondaryColor : null,
        child: const TabBar(
          tabs: tabs,
          isScrollable: true,
          indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 45),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    body: TabBarView(children: 
      Center(child: Text("Hello World",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),)),
    ]),
  ),
);
}
}
```

[image]